# C++ cout aligning output numbers

Tags: c++, formatting, cout

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << -0.152454345 << " " << -0.7545 << endl;
    cout << 0.15243 << " " << 0.9154878774 << endl;
}
```

Outputs:

```
-0.152454 -0.7545
0.15243 0.915488
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
-0.152454 -0.754500
 0.152430  0.915488
```

My solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << setw(9) << setfill(' ') << -0.152454345 << " ";
    cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << setw(9) << setfill(' ') << -0.7545 << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << setw(9) << setfill(' ') << 0.15243 << " ";
    cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << setw(9) << setfill(' ') << 0.9154878774 << endl;
}
```

The output is good, but the code is terrible. What can be done?
Here is my code https://ideone.com/6MKd31

Comment: Use stdio.h. iostream is bad for formatting.

Comment: You could write a function for it?

Comment: A nice guide that explains the basics of numeric formatting and shows good code examples: https://websites.umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/formatting.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Specifying an output format is always terrible. Anyway you can just omit to repeat stream modifiers that are conserved across input/output and repeat only those that are transients (`setw`):

```
// change state of the stream
cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << setfill(' ');
// output data
cout << setw(9) << -0.152454345  << " ";
cout << setw(9) << -0.7545       << endl;
cout << setw(9) << 0.15243       << " ";
cout << setw(9) <<  0.9154878774 << endl;
```

Comment: @Aconcagua why do you say so?

Answer (score 3):

This might not quite be what you want, but I thought I'd throw it out there anyway as it's very simple.

If you can tolerate a leading `+` for non-negative numbers then you can use

```
std::cout << std::showpos << /*ToDo - the rest of your output here*/
```

At least then everything lines up, with minimal effort.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem with streams once (but more complex, though), you could use a separate formatter object to avoid code repeating:

```
class F
{
    double v;
public:
    F(double v) : v(v) { };
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, F f)
    {
        s << setw(9) << v;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
std::cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << setfill(' '); // retained, see Jean's answer
std::cout << F(12.10) << ' ' << F(-10.12) << std::endl;
```

Depending on your needs and how frequently you use it, it might be overkill or not - decide yourself...

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function for it:

```
std::ostream& format_out(std::ostream& os, int precision, int width, char fill, double value)
{
    return os << std::fixed << std::setprecision(precision) << std::setw(width) << std::setfill(fill)
        << value;
}

int main()
{
    format_out(std::cout, 6, 9, ' ', -0.152454345) << '\n';
    format_out(std::cout, 6, 9, ' ', -0.7545) << '\n';
    format_out(std::cout, 6, 9, ' ', 0.15243) << '\n';
    format_out(std::cout, 6, 9, ' ', 0.9154878774) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit of necroposting, but it might still be useful to someone in the future. We can use a lamda expression (or the equivalent function) to make the formatting less painful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  auto format = [](std::ostream &os) -> std::ostream& {
    return os << fixed << setprecision(6) << setw(9) << setfill(' ');
  };


  cout << format << -0.152454345 << " " << format << -0.7545      << "\n";
  cout << format << 0.15243      << " " << format << 0.9154878774 << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
-0.152454 -0.754500
 0.152430  0.915488
```

Comment: Clever, and I like to learn about lambda, so +1, but I won't use this for formatting right now